# zurb foundation accordion specific clickability

Tags: zurb-foundation, jquery-ui-accordion

So my boss was requesting for me to have the accordions only clickable based on the course title: and not the labels or the rest of the row http://new.omegadesignla.com/courses/math.php

would this even be possible and would it even be worth the work? How would this even be done? I'm assuming i'd have to edition the foundation.js file for the accordion section.

Answer (score 0):

Optional Javascript Configuration
JS

```
    $(document).foundation({
  accordion: {
    // specify the class used for accordion panels
    content_class: 'content',
    // specify the class used for active (or open) accordion panels
    active_class: 'active',
    // allow multiple accordion panels to be active at the same time
    multi_expand: false,
    // allow accordion panels to be closed by clicking on their headers
    // setting to false only closes accordion panels when another is opened
    toggleable: true
  }
});
```

Comment: thanks i saw this in the foundation docs but it doesnt really solve the issue.